# Difference between append(“svg:g”) and append(“svg:svg”)?

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart

i am new in d3.js and i am trying to make a pie chart but in the structure i got two append one is  append(“svg : g”) and another one is  append(“svg: svg”),i am bit confused.So what is the difference between in this two append method?

Comment: The first `svg` in both your examples is the namespace. Once you're using d3 (and if you are not using another XML with the same names) you can drop them without any problem (so, "svg:svg" is the same of "svg" and "svg:g" is the same of "g"). That being said, the difference is that "svg:svg"  appends an SVG, and "svg:g" appends a group.

Comment: @Furtado ,thanks  i got the point.